# How to redirect to a page only after ajax is complete on the page I am redirecting to?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am redirectin to a page by calling an ajax. The problem is that I want to only redirect to the page after ajax finished loading on the page I want to redirect to. The code below redirects me to the page I want to redirect to but before the window.location = url is called I need the page to finish loading ajax first. How can I do it?

```
$('.js-next-generation-loader').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var obj = $(this);

        var url = obj.attr("href");

        $('body').loader("light");

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function (data, text) {
                window.location = url;                    
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {                    
                window.location = url;
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Given that you `preventDefault()` the event, and only redirect in the AJAX callbacks, your code appears to already be doing what you ask. Do you have an issue with it?

Comment: Lemme get this straight. You have a page (say Page A). You have and AJAX call running here. After execution of this request you want to load another Page B. But Page B has a different AJAX call, and you want Page B to execute the AJAX call and on its success and redirect to this page (page B)?

Comment: @MrBones That's exactly my problem. Don't know how to first finish executing the ajax on page B and then redirect to it

Comment: Not possible. Unless you have a Single Page Application.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.js-next-generation-loader').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var obj = $(this);

    var url = obj.attr("href");

    $('body').loader("light");

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (data, text) {
            //you can use this
            if(data==success){    
               window.location = url;
            } 
          //or you can use
          //This code will go to the desired link after 4 seconds 
          setTimeout(function(){
              window.location = url;
          }, 4000);                  
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {                    
            window.location = url;
        }
    });

});
```